# want to show interval days between two selected dates in two months calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am new in jquery. I am facing a problem. I am using jquery ui calendar. I want to show date difference and there will be two months calendar. Also start date and end date will be highlighted and in between dates also highlighted but in different color. Also in bottom of the calendar it will display the total interval days(start date to end date)i.e. 5days. 10days.

I have done highlighted parts. But I am unable to show the calculation parts i.e 5days, 10 days .

Please follow the link for your reference

https://docs.google.com/a/webskitters.com/file/d/0B1t10tawDw7wQnpQa09HM0hWdEE/edit

or

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1t10tawDw7wQnpQa09HM0hWdEE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: **What do mean by five days?**  In picture you have date-range **3/22 to 3/26** inbetween it has only 3 day and you have done by highlighting it.

Comment: please share the code you have tried?

Comment: 22,23,24,25,26 -> this "5 days" i want to display in the calendar

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to get the input values from the `from` and `to` text inputs and compute their difference in JS.

```
( (new Date($('#to').val())).getTime() - (new Date($('#from').val())).getTime() ) / (24*60*60*1000)
```

Should give you 5.

Comment: I have already done the calculation but i am unable to show in that particular place in two months "highlighted" calendar